# Prevent page refresh in wordpress form submission

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have setup a small form in my wordpress website.But when I press the submit button the page reloads and goes to the top although the form gets submitted and a success message is displayed.How to prevent this?I want the page to stay at the form section.I dont want users to scroll down to find what happened to the form.

PHP:

```
  <?php 
  //If the form is submitted
  if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    //Check to see if the honeypot captcha field was filled in
    if(trim($_POST['checking']) !== '') {
        $captchaError = true;
    } else {

        //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
        if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
            $nameError = 'You forgot to enter your name.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
        }

        //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
        if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
            $emailError = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
            $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        }

        //Check to make sure comments were entered  
        if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
            $commentError = 'You forgot to enter your comments.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
                $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
            } else {
                $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
            }
        }

        //If there is no error, send the email
        if(!isset($hasError)) {

            $emailTo = 'me@somedomain.com';
            $subject = 'Contact Form Submission from '.$name;
            $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
            $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
            $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

            mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

            if($sendCopy == true) {
                $subject = 'You emailed Your Name';
                $headers = 'From: Your Name <noreply@somedomain.com>';
                mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
            }

            $emailSent = true;

        }
    }
  } ?>


  <?php get_header(); ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/contact-form.js"></script>



  <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>

    <div class="thanks">
        <h1>Thanks, <?=$name;?></h1>
        <p>Your email was successfully sent. I will be in touch soon.</p>
    </div>

  <?php } else { ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
            <p class="error">There was an error submitting the form.<p>
        <?php } ?>

        <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">

            <ol class="forms">
                <li><label for="contactName">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="requiredField" />
                    <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                        <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span> 
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>

                <li><label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="requiredField email" />
                    <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                        <span class="error"><?=$emailError;?></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>

                <li class="textarea"><label for="commentsText">Comments</label>
                    <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" rows="20" cols="30" class="requiredField"><?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?></textarea>
                    <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
                        <span class="error"><?=$commentError;?></span> 
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <li class="inline"><input type="checkbox" name="sendCopy" id="sendCopy" value="true"<?php if(isset($_POST['sendCopy']) && $_POST['sendCopy'] == true) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> /><label for="sendCopy">Send a copy of this email to yourself</label></li>
                <li class="screenReader"><label for="checking" class="screenReader">If you want to submit this form, do not enter anything in this field</label><input type="text" name="checking" id="checking" class="screenReader" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['checking']))  echo $_POST['checking'];?>" /></li>
                <li class="buttons"><input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" /><button type="submit">Email me &raquo;</button></li>
            </ol>
        </form>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

JS:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form#contactForm').submit(function() {
            $('form#contactForm .error').remove();
            var hasError = false;
            $('.requiredField').each(function() {
                if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">You forgot to enter your '+labelText+'.</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                } else if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                    if(!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
                        var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                        $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">You entered an invalid '+labelText+'.</span>');
                        hasError = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            if(!hasError) {
                $('form#contactForm li.buttons button').fadeOut('normal', function() {
                    $(this).parent().append('<img src="/wp-content/themes/td-v3/images/template/loading.gif" alt="Loading&hellip;" height="31" width="31" />');
                });
                var formInput = $(this).serialize();
                $.post($(this).attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
                    $('form#contactForm').slideUp("fast", function() {                 
                        $(this).before('<p class="thanks"><strong>Thanks!</strong> Your email was successfully sent. I check my email all the time, so I should be in touch soon.</p>');
                    });
                });
            }

            return false;

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just prevent default behavior of HTML Form when submitted:

```
 $('form#contactForm').submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: I have tried adding the above code but the problem still persists :(